# ¿Cómo especificar el separador de decimal y de miles en C#?

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente problema, desarrolle una aplicación para la empresa que trabajo, pero algunos usuarios usan una configuración regional distinta a la que se desarrollo la app, por lo que en la aplicación la numeración se ve con una puntuación distinta lo que me causa problemas en los procesos de guardado en la base de datos entre otros. Lo que necesito es una opción para que la aplicación tome por defecto el punto como separador de miles y la coma como separador de decimales.
Investigue un poco y estoy probando este código pero no me funciona del todo, la separación de miles sigue con la coma en vez de el punto que es lo que necesito.

```
CultureInfo cultura1 = new CultureInfo("es-CL");

cultura1.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",";
cultura1.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
cultura1.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".";
cultura1.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultura1;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultura1;
```

Alguien podría ayudarme con esto por favor.

ya que continúan mostrándose los valores numéricos así [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos datos solo cambian su puntuación si yo manualmente voy al panel de control -> configuración regional y cambio el separador de miles por un punto y el separador de decimales por una coma. Pero esto no lo puedo hacer en todas los equipos que presenten este problema acá en la empresa por lo que estoy buscando una opción como esta que funcione

Comment: en donde seguis viendo eso?

Comment: No especificas donde pones este código. La cultura se establece para un hilo en concreto, es posible que se te esté escapando por alguno otro. Prueba a asignar la cultura en [DefaulThreadCurrentCulture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Globalization_CultureInfo_DefaultThreadCurrentCulture) si estas es .net 4.5 +

Comment: El código lo pongo en el Main() del archivo Program.cs, que según leí en otros foros es donde debe ir.

Comment: y donde es que ves que no se cambian los separadores??? podrias aclararlo?

Comment: Y esos valores de donde salen?? la forma de mostrar cosas por pantalla no tiene nada que ver con la cultura de tu sistema...

Comment: Dentro de toda la aplicación, estoy mostrando datos numéricos, ejemplo valor del dolar, montos de venta, etc. Estos datos solo cambian su puntuación si yo manualmente voy al panel de control -> configuración regional y cambio el separador de miles por un punto y el separador de decimales por una coma. Pero esto no lo puedo hacer en todas los equipos que presenten este problema acá en la empresa por lo que estoy buscando una opción como esta que funcione.

Comment: Probaste a asignar tu cultura modificada en DefaultThreadCurrentCulture?

Comment: Donde y como hago eso?

Comment: En lugar de `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultura1;` pon `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;`. Y lo mismo para `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultura1;` -> `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultura1`

Comment: Acabo de hacerlo y no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Si tu separador de decimales esta indicado por una coma o un punto dependiendo
de puedes usar

```
public static decimal TextoaDecimal(string s)
{
    var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
    clone.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
    clone.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
 // ejemplo string s = "1,14535765" o string s="1.141516";
    decimal d = decimal.Parse(s, clone);

    return d;
}
```